# table layout wrapping text android

Tags: android

I'm creating dynamic table. The first row is static.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#DEDEDE" >
<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#DEDEDE" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/DarkGray" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:text="Аватар"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:text="Выезд"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:text="Откуда"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:text="Куда"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:text="М/Ц"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

the second one and other rows are dynamic, and they are filled programmatically

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TableRow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#DEDEDE" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageStatus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textVuezd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textOtkuda"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textKuda"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textSeatsPrice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

</TableRow>
```

I show this table as dialog and got this:

```
http://www.autostarkiev.com.ua/gg.png
```

due to font size I can see only half of the whole table. How do I make text in text view wrap, so i can see the whole table?

Comment: Google Translate forever ;) !!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For each `TextView` in `TableRow` replace "match_parent" with 0dp and use weight instead.

Change the line:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

To the lines:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

if you want a column to be bigger than others, just change weight from 1 to a bigger number.

Comment: thanks. it worked, but the static part goes wrong http://www.autostarkiev.com.ua/gg%20(2).png

Comment: Try using smaller text size if texts don't feet in one line, or change the weight.

Comment: You have to set layout_weight for each row in the table.